# Where can I find a SE community's purpose description?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm looking for the community focused on *Windows OS* issues.
I suppose it is [Super User](https://superuser.com/), but I didn't find enough to be sure about that.

Thus, for any generic Stack Exchange community, where can I find a description of the subjects it proposes to embrace?

Comment: The description is unfortunately only a single sentence often and the list of topics that are on-topic is a bit hidden. You don't ask for it, but I think that your question actually highlights that there is potential to improve and make the description and the topics that a site embrace more extensive and more visible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The help center - specifically the [on topic page](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). The [tour](https://superuser.com/tour) would give you a higher level overview of things, and the [sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) page will give you a quick overview of what's on topic on sites across the network

Comment: Actually, search by site's most used tags can show it explicitly, since topic page can be a bit generic sometimes.

Comment: @artu-hnrq Be careful using tags to infer what's on-topic, that's not their purpose.

Comment: This works great the vast majority of the time. An exception is that some smaller (beta) communities don't have sufficient details in either the on-topic help page, or the tour. ([Tezos.se] is an example: [tour](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/tour)/ [on-topic](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))

Answer (score 6):

There is the [list of all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic), where each site has its own, very short description.

That should help you eliminate quite a few sites already. But to be absolutely sure, there is no single list. You will have to go to each site's `/help/on-topic` page to see which types of questions are (un)welcome on a specific site.

Another thing you could try is to do a [networkwide search](https://stackexchange.com/search), this could help you find sites where there are already questions using your keywords. Again, make sure to check out that sites `/help/on-topic` page before asking: Just because you hit a keyword doesn't mean your specific question about that keyword is welcome there too!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the first place to look into is the site's tour page (`/tour`), then the site's `/help/on-topic` page but if that is not enough look at `/tags` but more specifically look at the tag excerpts, not just the tag names.

On Super User, the top 2, 3, and 4 tags are `windows`, `windows-7` and `windows-10`, respectively.

[image]

- `[windows]`: For questions not specific to a single version of Microsoft Windows. Otherwise, use a more specific tag such as `[windows-7]` or `[windows-10]`.
- `[windows-7]`: For questions specific to Windows 7. Use `[windows]` instead for questions involving Windows in general.
- `[windows-10]`: For questions specific to Windows 10. Use `[windows]` instead for questions involving Windows in general.

On the tag wikis you could find even more details. Following is the current wiki for `windows`:

> If your problem only happens when using a specific release, or you're
> only looking for help under a single version of Windows, use that tag
> instead.
>
> [image: Microsoft Windows Logo]
>
> This general tag includes, but is not limited to, issues that happen
> across:
>
> ### Consumer Windows versions:
>
> - [windows-95]
> - [windows-98]
> - [windows-2000]
> - [windows-xp]
> - [windows-vista]
> - [windows-7]
> - [windows-8]
> - [windows-8.1]
> - [windows-10]
>
> ### Windows server versions:
>
> - [windows-server]
> - [windows-server-2000]
> - [windows-server-2003]
> - [windows-server-2008]
> - [windows-server-2008-r2]
> - [windows-server-2012]
> - [windows-server-2012-r2]
> - [windows-sbs]
> - [windows-home-server]
>
> ### Windows Mobile/Phone versions:
>
> - [windows-mobile]
> - [windows-phone]
> - [windows-ce]